# ¿Porqué el texto se pinta en una sola linea?

Tags: java, android, canvas

Estoy recibiendo texto de un control editText en ese campo se recibiran muchos caracteres (texto) he hecho casi de todo los ejemplos que he encontrado pero siempre fallan.

```
  TextPaint mTextPaint=new TextPaint();
            StaticLayout mTextLayout = new StaticLayout(observaciones.getText().toString(), mTextPaint, canvas.getWidth(),
                    Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 2.0f, 0.0f, false);
            int x=50;
            int y=530;
            
            for (String line: observaciones.getText().toString().split("\n")){
                canvas.drawText(line,x,y,mTextPaint);
                y += mTextPaint.descent()-mTextPaint.ascent();

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Es correcto usar `drawText()` pero para que aumente la posición en el eje "y" usa

```
y += mTextPaint.getTextSize();
```

de esta forma:

```
for (String line: observaciones.getText().toString().split("\n")){
     canvas.drawText(line, x, y, mTextPaint);
     y += mTextPaint.getTextSize();
}
```

Comment: Solucionado, perfecto, muchas gracias

Comment: Excelente @sebastiancorcho!, recuerda marcar como solución la respuesta que ayude a solucionar el problema planteado en la preguna, revisa [tour], saludos.